# Correct way to access MS Graph data on blazor server-side app with Individual User Acconts

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-msal

I have a web application build in Blazor (ASP.NET Core) server-side. The application is multi-tenant and I need to control who has access, thus I use my own user database (DefaultIdentity) stored in an SQL database.

Now I need access to Microsoft Graph (for some of the users). I have this working by using application level access, but would like to avoid having to have the local IT admin set this up in their Azure AD - and I want to adhere to the "least privilege principle".

So I would like to be able to add a sign-in page/functionality where a specific user (after they have logged on using my local user database) can give my app autorization+consent to retrieve Calendar.Read permission through Microsoft Graph.

How should I do this?

What I think I've learned is

- I should use the OAuth2.0 Authorization Code Flow
- My application is a confidential application (I have a secure server side) - but this prevents me from using AquireTokenInteractive!? So should I use IPublicClientApplication?

All the examples I can find use Azure AD for signing in users. Is there an exmple where the authorization code flow is "manually" implemented that I can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have a working solution, but would like to hear whether some of you have any input - any caveats or pitfalls that I haven't seen.

My solution is the following:

I'm using the "standard flow" for getting a PublicClientApplication

```
        IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(publicAppClientId)
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")                
            .Build();
        
        TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(app.UserTokenCache);
        
        var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
        IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
                              
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        try
        {
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopesList, firstAccount)
                        .ExecuteAsync();                
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {                
            try
            {
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopesList)
                    .ExecuteAsync();                 
            }
            catch (MsalException msalex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error acquiring token silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}");
            return;
        }

        if (authResult != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Access token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{authResult.AccessToken}");                
                           
            // Use the token
            InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(app, scopesList);
            GraphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);                
        }
    }
```

The I've added a Distributed SQL cache using a TokenCacheHelper

```
 public class TokenCacheHelper
 {
    private IDistributedCache _cache;
    private string lookUpAccount = string.Empty;
    private byte[] token = null;

    public TokenCacheHelper(IDistributedCache cache, string user)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        lookUpAccount = user;
    }

    public void EnableSerialization(ITokenCache tokenCache)
    {
        tokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
        tokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
    }
    
    private void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        if (token == null)
        {
            token = _cache.Get(lookUpAccount);
        }
        args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(token);
    }

    private void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        if (args.HasStateChanged)
        {
            token = args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3();
            _cache.Set(lookUpAccount, token);
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the DistributedSqlServerCache in the startup.cs with "infinite" timeout on the tokens

```
services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDbContext");
            options.SchemaName = "dbo";
            options.TableName = "TestCache";
            options.DefaultSlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(300);
            options.ExpiredItemsDeletionInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(300);
        });
```

All this seems to be working. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm working on a similar client/server system. Question: How do you get `firstAccount` which you are passing to `AcquireTokenSilent`?

Comment: Via this      var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
                  IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Thank you! Tried it - GetAccountsAsync() delivers me an empty list :( - However, when I use "AcquireTokenInteractive(), then I get a list presented in the UI at rutime.  I wonder how I can access this list programmatically?

Comment: It did so for me as well, until I implemented the TokenCaching, then it supplies me with my account. That is, after I have run the first AcquireTokenInteractive and thereby saved my token in the TokenCache.

I use an SQL TokenCache with a very long expiration, thus so far MSAL has been able to automatically renew the tokens and the use only needs to sign-in/acknowledge once.